# When to use async in generic libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task, repository-pattern

I was recently looking for nice example of generic repository pattern and was confused by a totally different topic. `Async` `await`. This is simplified interface:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{ 
    Task<TEntity> GetById(int id);
}
```

and these are two examples of implementation of this interface:

**A:**

```
public async Task<TEntity> GetById(int id)
{
    return await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>()
                .AsNoTracking()
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);
}
```

**B:**

```
public Task<T> GetById(int id) => Context.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
```

In both cases it's method from a generic `RepositoryBase` class, which will be inherited by real `Repository` classes. In one case `async await` is used, in the second case *not*. Why?

and follow up question: If there IS a difference, when should we use `async await`, when should we just return the `Task`?

Comment: In your case with a single return at the end of the method it should make no difference. When you start doing more work on the value before returning you need to await.

Comment: @Joey are you saying the the B is correct? Is it different than A ?

Comment: I don't see any reason to use async/await in method A. Times to use `await` are: When there is code you want to run after the async operation has completed, or when the async call is inside a `using` block. It has nothing to do with whether you are using/writing a generic library.

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html

Comment: @IshThomas, nope, it's just that you're awaiting unnecessarily, i.e. you're letting the compiler split the method apart at the `await` and wrap the result in a new task, which is identical to the task you've awaited in the first place. It's not a big deal, though, and no one except you will notice, as the method looks the same from the API side. (Might even be that the compiler optimizes this exact pattern to what you have in B)

Comment: Thanks all for help. It makes more sense now. I found option A in this tutorial: https://codingblast.com/entity-framework-core-generic-repository/ I didn't miss anything right? They don't have to use async await (beside Create, where they add async and then save async)

Comment: FWIW, using the *repository pattern* combined with *EF* is generally magnitudes worse than the extra `await`. A redundant *IAsyncStatemachine* implementation will generate a small amount *CIL* and has optimizations, a badly hewn repository is setting you up for a big refactor in the future,a lot of testing, and a boat load more *CIL*.

Comment: @Joey in this tutorial https://blog.zhaytam.com/2019/03/14/generic-repository-pattern-csharp/ they use `async await` for `GetAll` but they don't for `GetById`. Why is that? In the same tutorial they used both approaches.

Comment: @IshThomas: They might not know, care or put effort into making sure the code is consistent. It sometimes seems to me that a _lot_ of tutorials out there are written by people like me with lots of dangerous half-knowledge and then it becomes more of a self-marketing tool and about regularly posting content than actually about teaching people.

Comment: As a side note, in the first case (with await) you are expected to configure the await: [C#: Why you should use ConfigureAwait(false) in your library code](https://medium.com/bynder-tech/c-why-you-should-use-configureawait-false-in-your-library-code-d7837dce3d7f)

Comment: `async` is a keyword related to the implementation of the method, not related to the signature. It is thus not used when declaring abstract members or interfaces, but used when you declare the actual method containing the async code. This instructs the compiler to rewrite the method body using the async rewriter rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was recently looking for nice example of generic repository pattern

The generic repository pattern is generally considered an antipattern, precisely because it's too generic. Personally, I prefer a ports-and-adapters style of data layer abstraction, which lets the app define the DAL methods it needs. Though in many cases, straight-up EF works fine (this seems to be the most common choice by far).

> In one case async await is used, in the second case not. Why?

There are a few considerations about when to [elide `async`/`await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html). It mostly comes down to exception handling. Methods returning tasks should place exceptions on those tasks, not raise the exceptions directly; that's the implicit contract for methods with asynchronous signatures.

So, this code will (incorrectly) throw directly if `Context` or `Set<T>` throw:

```
public Task<T> GetById(int id) => Context.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
```

As a general rule, keeping `async`/`await` is the safe choice; eliding them is a minor performance optimization that should only be done after [considering the pitfalls](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).

Comment: Read your article, it's great. This is exactly what I was looking for. About ports-and-adapters, do you know any nice sample github repository?

Comment: Hmm.. correct me if I'm wrong by "ports-and-adapters" approach looks like Repository pattern without BaseRepository. I'm not forced (I don't inherit) methods that I don't need. In each Repository I implement only stuff I need. Then inject these Repositories to the Domain via interfaces. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @IshThomas: I don't know of a sample github repository for ports-and-adapters, but there are several blog posts about it. With the generic repository pattern, every repository defines a "this is what a repository looks like for all possible types", and it's just a matter of time before that's not enough and then you end up with an application making assumptions about how transactions work or other details of the DAL. With ports, the *application* defines the interface it wants for its repository, and this will look different for each type being stored.